# Does the following simple set have a name

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, definition

This question might sound ridiculous, but I want an answer.

For every natural $N$ and $k < N$ define the set

$$
S_{N,k} = \left\{ (i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k) \in \mathbb{N} : 0 \leq i_1 <  i_2 < \ldots < i_k < N \right\}
$$

So for example if $N=5$ and $k=3$ we have the following enumeration

```
0 1 2
0 1 3
0 1 4
0 2 3
0 2 4
0 3 4
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
2 3 4
```

Does $S_{N,k}$ have a name?

Comment: You may want to write them as $\color{red}{(}i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k\color{red}{)}$ otherwise it's not clear if you're considering a set or a $k$-tuple.

Comment: @jjagmath thank you!

Comment: Maybe the set of increasing $k$-tuples of nonnegative integers less than $N$. Isomorphic to the set of $k$-combinations of $0$ to $N-1$.

Comment: I was hoping maybe a name more related to the geometry of it. For example $\left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1 \right\}$ is *half a square*.

Comment: Because it is in a natural bijection with the set of $k$-element subsets of $\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$, I don't think it is likely to have a completely "standard" name.

Comment: Write $[n]$ for the total order $(\{0, \ldots, n-1\}, <)$. Then another name for your set $S_{N,k}$ is the set of [strictly monotone maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#In_order_theory) from $[k]$ to $[N+1]$